# Resolve Circular Dependency RoboGuice

Tags: android, dependency-injection, guice, roboguice

I seems to have a problem with a circular dependency in my app. I have tested all the classes and they work well, however I am not able to instantiate them when running my app.

The root of the problem is in this class

```
public class HttpClientProvider implements Provider<HttpClient> {

    @Inject
    private UserAgent userAgent;
    @Inject
    private HttpResponseInterceptor interceptor;

    private DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();


    @Override
    public HttpClient get() {
        httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, userAgent.getUserAgent());
        httpClient.addResponseInterceptor(interceptor);
        return httpClient;
    }
}
```

This class provides the httpClient and adds an interceptor. The interceptor looks like this provider is used to provider the httpclient for this class

```
public class ServerCommunicator implements ServerCommunicator {

    public static final String URL = "http://something.com/";

    private HttpClient httpClient;
    private HttpContext httpContext;

    @Inject
    public ServerCommunicator(HttpClient httpClient, HttpContext httpContext) {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
        this.httpContext = httpContext;
    }

    @Override
    public HttpResponse post(String URN, String entity) throws IOException {
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL + URN);
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(entity));
        return httpClient.execute(httpPost, httpContext);
    }

    @Override
    public HttpResponse get(String URN) throws IOException {
        return httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(URL + URN),  httpContext);
    }

    @Override
    public HttpResponse delete(String URN) throws IOException {
        return httpClient.execute(new HttpDelete(URL + URN),  httpContext);
    }

}
```

The problems comes because the httpResponseInterceptor also uses the ServerCommunicator class to send requests to the server when the user is not authenitcated.

How to resolve this?

Comment: So HttpClientProvider relies on HttpResponseInterceptor which relies on ServerCommunicator which requires a HttpClient from the Provider. Can the HttpResponseInterceptor use a different HttpClient, i.e. one that is not intercepted?

Comment: It could but I solved it with making the ServerCommunicator a singleton. I will write an answer when I get chance